# Deployment of multi-page web app with minikube

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, kubernetes, minikube

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to use minikube in order to deploy a multi-page nodejs-mongoDB web app. I have created my app, I have dockerized it and now I'm trying to deploy it locally using minikube. When I execute minikube `minikube service my-app --url` in a Unix shell I obtain an IP. Putting the IP in the browser I obtain the index page but trying to use the button to switch to another page the browser doesn't switch. I am sure the app is correct because executing it locally I obtain what I want but I cannot understand why this fails in minikube. I am new and I am not an expert. Can anyone help me?

Here the HTML code for the index page :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>

    <form method="get" action="./insert/item">
      <input type="submit" value="Insert">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here the server side of the index page:

```html
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/insert/item', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/insert');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: How are you deploying it to Kubernetes, do you have a deployment definition?

Comment: Yes for sure.. Here a part of its and in the next comment the second part : # APP DEPLOYMENT

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: my-app
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-app-exposed
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-app-exposed

Comment: spec:
      containers:
      - image : localhost:5000/my-app:0.1.0
        name: docker-node-mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          protocol: TCP

---

# APP SERVICE

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: my-app
  name: my-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    run: my-app-exposed
  type: NodePort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have a JS error related to CORS security (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). This is preventing one website to interact with another one through JS.

You can check that by using Developer tools in :

- chrome (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)
- firefox (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Outils/Console_JavaScript).

Your service might be good fo running locally but not on a remote website that the k8s service ip is presenting you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you suggest me a way to solve the problem?

Comment: Depends of the output of the JS console you can provide. Since we are still not sure this is the error you are facing.

Comment: @Anto if you can't provide any feedback you should accept this as the correct answer since this is the most obvious answer given what you reported